Minimum number of subsets to cover all size-2 symmetric differences
Let $n=2k$. Find the minimum value of $m$, such that there exist $m$ "size-$k$" subsets of $[n]$, denoted as $S_1, ..., S_m$, satisfying
$$
\{i, j\} \in \{S_p \triangle S_q \mid 1 \le p < q \le m\}
$$
for all $1 \le i < j \le n$. Here, $\triangle$ refers to the symmetric difference between two sets.
My attempt:

It is easy to construct the following subsets that satisfy the condition:
$$
[k], \quad ([k] \backslash \{i\}) \cup \{j\}, 1 \le i \le k, k+1 \le j \le 2k.
$$
Therefore, we have $m \le k^2+1$. Using a more fine-grained construction, we can further improve the upper bound to $m \le \lceil \frac{(k+1)^2}{2} \rceil$.

What's more interesting is the lower bound. Currently I didn't figure out a good way to do it, and the best that I can achieve is trivial: $m \ge n$ (this is because each pair of subsets contributes to at most one $(i, j)$ pair)


My question: Can we obtain a non-trivial lower bound for $m$? My intuition from the construction is that the lower bound should be quadratic (in $n$) as well. Furthermore, is it possible to obtain a matching lower and upper bound? Is the current upper bound tight? (Update: the current upper bound is not tight, credit to @
RobPratt)
Related Question: Mike and Rob suggested the following question, and while they do share some similarities at first sight, they are fundamentally different. An easy way to distinguish these two questions is that, the current question has a trivial lower bound $m \ge n$, whereas Mike proved that the answer to the referred question is $\log n$.
Upper Bound: Currently, the best upper bound that I obtained is via the following construction. We first consider the following subsets:
$$
[k], [k] \backslash \{1\} \cup \{k+1\}, ..., [k] \backslash \{1\} \cup \{2k-1\}, \\ [k] \backslash \{1\} \cup \{2k\}, [k] \backslash \{2\} \cup \{2k\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{k\} \cup \{2k\}.
$$
Now we only need to consider the cross pairs between $\{2, ..., k\}$ and $\{k+1, ..., 2k-1\}$. We introduce the following subsets:
$$
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{k+1, k+2\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{k+1, k+2\}, \\
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{k+3, k+4\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{k+3, k+4\}, \\
... \\
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{2k-2, 2k-1\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{2k-2, 2k-1\}.
$$
The key insight is that each subset here creates two new pairs: for instance, by comparing $[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{k+1, k+2\}$ with $[k] \backslash \{1\} \cup \{k+1\}$ and $[k] \backslash \{1\} \cup \{k+2\}$, we obtain two pairs $(2, k+1)$ and $(2, k+2)$.
Also note that the construction implicitly assumes $k$ to be odd, but the case where $k$ is even can be handled similarly. In particular, in addition to
$$
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{k+1, k+2\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{k+1, k+2\}, \\
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{k+3, k+4\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{k+3, k+4\}, \\
... \\
[k] \backslash \{1, 2\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2\},
$$
we also add the following subsets:
$$
[k] \backslash \{1, 2, 3\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2, 2k-1\}, [k] \backslash \{1, 4, 5\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2, 2k-1\}, \cdots, [k] \backslash \{1, k-2, k-1\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2, 2k-1\},
$$
and $[k] \backslash \{1, k-1, k\} \cup \{2k-3, 2k-2, 2k-1\}$. For both the odd and even case, since there are $(k-1)^2$ cross pairs, and that each subset can handle $2$ cross pairs, the number of subsets is $\lceil \frac{(k-1)^2}{2}\rceil$.
Finally, the total number of subsets in this construction is
$$
2k + \lceil \frac{(k-1)^2}{2}\rceil = \lceil \frac{(k+1)^2}{2}\rceil.
$$
New Update: Rob constructed a valid example with $24$ subsets for $n=12, k=6$, showing that the upper bound $\lceil \frac{(k+1)^2}{2}\rceil$ is not tight. In light of this, obtaining an analytical formula of $m$ for general $n$ might be too hard.

Hi Mike and Rob, thanks for the response, but I think this question is fundamentally different from the question in the link. In particular, 1) here all subsets are required to have the same size $|S_i| = k$; 2) the statement in the question is also fundamentally different, as a matter of fact, my question has a trivial lower bound $n$, whereas Mike proved that $\log n$ is both sufficient and achievable.

I'm sorry if I'm being dumb but this question seems to be different. In the refferenced one for $k=2$ the exmple turns out to be $S={{01,11},{10,11}}$. But there is a single symmetric difference here, hence not all pairs are achieved.

@Mirnegg The example he builds in this problem is of size $k$ (last paragraph) but it is fundamentally different. It just answers a different problem...

@agent_cracker103 Thanks for speaking up!

For $n=12$, a better upper bound is $24$: {0,1,2,3,4,5}
{0,1,2,3,4,6}
{0,1,2,3,5,6}
{0,1,2,4,5,6}
{0,1,3,4,5,6}
{0,2,3,4,5,6}
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
{0,1,2,3,4,7}
{0,2,3,4,5,7}
{0,2,3,4,6,7}
{1,2,3,5,6,7}
{0,1,4,5,6,7}
{1,2,3,5,6,8}
{0,1,4,5,6,8}
{0,2,3,4,7,8}
{1,2,3,5,6,9}
{0,1,4,5,6,9}
{0,2,3,4,7,9}
{1,2,3,5,6,10}
{0,1,4,5,6,10}
{0,2,3,4,7,10}
{1,2,3,5,6,11}
{0,1,4,5,6,11}
{0,2,3,4,7,11}

@RobPratt Thanks, this is useful to know. In this case I think it might be too hard to find an analytical formula for general $n$. Do you think there is a way to obtain a non-trivial lower bound? Also, do you mind sharing how you come up with this 24 example? Thanks a lot.

I found that solution via integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable for each $k$-subset and for each symmetric difference of cardinality two.

Here is a construction with only $3n$ sets.
First, assume $k$ is even. Partition $[n]$ into four sets $A,B,C,D$ of size $k/2$, and let $a,b,c,d$ be arbitrary elements of $A,B,C,D$ respectively. Now take the following sets:

$A \cup B \cup \{x\} - \{a\}$ for $x \in C \cup D$.
$A \cup C \cup \{x\} - \{a\}$ for $x \in B \cup D$.
$A \cup D \cup \{x\} - \{a\}$ for $x \in B \cup C$.
$B \cup C \cup \{x\} - \{b\}$ for $x \in A \cup D$.
$B \cup D \cup \{x\} - \{b\}$ for $x \in A \cup C$.
$C \cup D \cup \{x\} - \{c\}$ for $x \in A \cup B$.

A symmetric difference of two sets in the first group gets us all pairs $\{x,y\} \subset C \cup D$. Similarly, we get all pairs in $B \cup D$, $B \cup C$, $A \cup D$, $A \cup C$, and $A \cup B$ from the other five groups. But every pair is contained in at least one of these six sets!
If $k$ is odd, then let's say $A$ and $B$ have size $\frac{k-1}{2}$ while $C$ and $D$ have size $\frac{k+1}{2}$. For four out of six sets above, the construction still works. For the first group, $A \cup B$ only has size $k-1$, so it's enough to use $A \cup B \cup \{x\}$. For the last group, $C \cup D$ has size $k+1$, so we should use $C \cup D \cup \{x\} - \{c,d\}$.

This is a truly beautiful and elegant construction, thanks so much Misha :)
